# Jsoup parse very slow

Tags: java, android, jsoup

At Intellij IDEA (or Eclipse) parse about 10 sec. It's cool.
But when I take the same code at Android studio it take about 5 min. Very slow....
What I do wrong? How can I improve it?

public void run() {

```
            Document docMake;
            Document docModel;
            try {
                docMake = Jsoup
                        .connect("https://av.by/")
                        .get();

                Element selectMake = docMake
                        .select("option:containsOwn(Марка автомобиля)")
                        .get(0);
                Elements makes = selectMake.siblingElements();

                List<MakeCarRealm> listMakes = new ArrayList<>();
                MakeCarRealm makeCarRealm;

                for (Element make : makes) {

                    makeCarRealm = new MakeCarRealm(make.text(), Integer.valueOf(make.attr("value")));
                    List<ModelRealm> listModels = new ArrayList<>();

                    docModel = Jsoup
                            .connect("https://cars.av.by/search?brand_id%5B%5D=" + make.attr("value") + "&model_id%5B%5D=0&year_from=&year_to=&currency=USD&price_from=&price_to=")
                            .get();

                    Element selectModel = docModel
                            .select("option:containsOwn(Модель)")
                            .get(0);
                    Elements models = selectModel.siblingElements();

                    for (Element model : models) {
                        ModelRealm modelRealm = new ModelRealm(model.text(), Integer.valueOf(model.attr("value")));
                        listModels.add(modelRealm);
                    }
                    makeCarRealm.setModelsCarsR(listModels);
                    listMakes.add(makeCarRealm);
                }
                ChooseCarsRealm carsRealm = new ChooseCarsRealm(listMakes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: do you know which part is slow? The network part or the actual parsing?

Comment: @luksch
Parsing take more time.
I tried to download the page in String usual Hptp and then to throw in parsing. But it takes the same time.

 ssl=0x7f70b10780 sslRead buf=0x7f70858800 len=2048,timeo=15000
 ssl=0x7f70b10780 sslRead buf=0x7f70858800 len=2048,timeo=15000
 ssl=0x7f70b10780 sslRead buf=0x7f70858800 len=2048,timeo=15000